# SQL Query to Count IDs

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to write a SQL Query in MS Access to count the number of times each ID appears in a data set. The data set is formatted as follows:

```
ID    Time
1     12345
1     12346
1     12350
2     99999
2     99999
```

If the **Time** for one **ID** is within 3 seconds of another **Time** for that same **ID**, I only want it to be counted once. So the results should look like this:

```
ID    Count
1     2
2     1
```

The time column is not formatted as a datetime, so I can't use the datediff function. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You first need a function to round up (or down) to the nearest multiple of 3. See [here](http://allenbrowne.com/round.html#RoundUp) (allenbrowne) for example.

Comment: So if you have times for id=1: 12345,12346,12347,12348,12349,12350 what is the result you expect?

Comment: @forpas I would expect the count to be 2 in that scenario. 12345-12348 would be the first count, and 12349-12350 as the second count.

Comment: @forpas: That criteria doesn't match the original: _within 3 seconds of another Time for that same ID_. Following that, the count will be 1.

Comment: I believe this requires a recursive CTE, if you want to solve it in SQL.  Your best bet is to use a cursor.

Comment: What's the type of `Time`?  Do you need to worry about looping days (midnight to early the next morning)?  And what version of Access (or underlying DB)?  Also, to tweak @forpas's data, what do you expect for 12345,12346,12347,12348,12349,12350 (12345 is cleanly divisible by 3)?

Comment: Actually, the way that I worded it in the question (and the way @Gustav worded it) is what I'm looking for. I would expect the count of 12345,12346,12347,12348,12349,12350 to be 1. I believe the time might be the number of seconds to that point in the day, and I don't need to worry about looping days. I'm using Access 2013.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
SELECT ID, COUNT(newtime)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ID, Time\3 AS newtime FROM times)
GROUP BY ID
```

groups the `Time` field values in triples using the integer division for `Time\3` in Access.

Comment: The grouping on the time will be wrong - if you have `000002`, `000003`, `000004`, that's "within 3 seconds" (and should count as one), but your grouping will count it as two.  Note, however, that running groups like this are murder.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Why do you consider it wrong? If the values are 000001, 000002, 000003, 000004, 000005, 000006, ...  they will be grouped in triples as I already **mentioned**.

Comment: Because you're splitting them into truncation-based buckets, as opposed to running groups.  My example was if you _only_ had those seconds; the primary question is "what starts a unique time?".  Truncation posits it starts on a mathematical boundary, which may not have been recorded (the grouping for `000001` and `000002` starts on `000000`, for example), whereas running groups starts it "every" 3 seconds from whatever the start point is (and which is much harder to get).

Comment: *Because you're splitting them into truncation-based buckets* exactly and I **mentioned** that. This is the solution that I present and if the OP finds that it suits him then he will accept it. If you have something else to propose then go on.

Answer (score 0):

The comment provided by @Andy G worked for my purposes:

"You first need a function to round up (or down) to the nearest multiple of 3. See [here](http://allenbrowne.com/round.html#RoundUp) (allenbrowne) for example."

I rounded the time values to the nearest multiple of 3, and counted based on that criteria.

Comment: So this way you get triples of ids that count as 1. How is this different from the sql statement I proposed?